# Python Groupby omitting columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

dg:

```
thing1 thing2 thing3 thing4 thing5 thing6 thing7 ID 
NAN      1      NAN   NAN     NAN   NAN     NAN  222
NAN      NAN     3    NAN     NAN   NAN     NAN  222
NAN      NAN    NAN    2      NAN   NAN     NAN  222
 3       NAN    NAN   NAN     NAN   NAN      3   222
NAN      NAN    NAN   NAN     NAN   NAN     NAN  222
NAN      NAN    NAN   NAN      4    NAN     NAN  222
NAN      NAN    NAN   NAN     NAN    4      NAN  222
NAN       3     NAN     2     NAN   NAN     NAN  555
NAN      NAN     3    NAN     NAN   NAN     NAN  555
NAN      NAN    NAN   NAN     NAN   NAN     NAN  555
```

when I do a groupby like this:

```
dg = dg.groupby('ID').max().reset_index()
```

it produces the following ouput, omitting two columns, like this:

```
ID   thing2 thing3 thing4  thing5  thing7
222    1      3      2       4       3
555           3      2
```

The dataframe follows that pattern but I don't know why two columns are being omitted

**NAN values are np.nan**

Comment: What is the output for `dg.dtypes`? Are the missing columns definitely numerical?

Comment: actuallly I found that some values are string values 'N/A', I will try replacing those

Comment: That did it!! there was a random "N/A" string in the midst of all the np.nan values, which made it really hard to spot the error

Answer (score 1):

I found out I had a string "N/A" value in the midst of my np.nan values. Lesson is strings with integers can cause columns to disappear when doing groupby functions. The columns that didn't have "N/A" string didn't disappear upon doing groupby functions. When I replaced "N/A" strings with np.nan the columns didn't disappear when I did the groupby

Comment: `max(['N/A', 3, np.nan])` raises a TypeError. When the aggregation function raises an error, the `df.groupby(...).max()` operation omits that column from the result. That is why your original output was missing 2 columns.

Comment: So the mix of all three raised a typeError?

Comment: Yes, though comparing *two* objects of different type could be enough to raise a `TypeError` . In Python3, comparing builtin objects of different (non-numeric) type raises a `TypeError`. For example, comparing a `str` with an `int`, as in `'N/A' < 3` or `max(['N/A', 3])`, raises a `TypeError`. In Python2, comparison of different types [is allowed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). Given the behavior you describe, you must be using Python3.